# How to get a sub collection email

Tags: javascript, firebase, automation, google-cloud-firestore

so I am currently trying to get access to the email I access. it only prints the full string but I'm completely unsure of how to get just the email

```
function addLead() {
   db.collection('entities')
   .doc('0') // change to the current user id 
   .get().then((user)=>{
       if(user.exists){
           // now you can do something with user
           console.log(user.data())
       }
   });
  };  
addLead();
```

It prints out this:

```
{ email: '123googlemail.com', user: 'X', pass: 'XD' }
```

each time I take this email and use it, I would like it to then select the next id, which would be "1"

So it would go "entities/0/email" and then once its used go to "entities/1/email" etc

hoping someone can help

Answer (score 0):

So I Figured it out, you have to use the normal process but passing the (doc) to a function :

```
  db.collection('entities').doc("0").get().then(function(doc) {
    const passName = doc.data().pass;
    console.log(doc.data().pass);
```

Hope this will help anyone that gets stuck,
It goes to Entities, opens it up, finds the one with ID `0` then gets the details.